# django_plotly_dash: div tag is messing up rendering of dashboard

Tags: html, css, django, plotly-dash

I am working with django_plotly_dash to render dashboards within django template (from the doc, the dashboard can either be integrated as an iframe or in the DOM elements of the page. I chose to go the iframe road.

The dashboard nevers takes the full screen on page. it is stucked on a small window.

Looking at the dev tools in my browser, I found which div element is causing the issue, however, I dont know where it is come from because it is nowhere to be found on my code.

here is my code:

```
{% load plotly_dash %}




                <div class="{% plotly_class name='report' %}" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
                   <div style="position:absolute,top:0"> {% plotly_app name='report' initial_arguments=context %}
                       </div>
                </div>
```

but then now, here is what the source code look like with tools:

```
                <div class="django-plotly-dash django-plotly-dash-iframe django-plotly-dash-app-report" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
                   <div style="position:absolute,top:0"> 
<div style="
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10.0%;
    height: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    ">
  <iframe src="/django_plotly_dash/app/report/initial/dpd-initial-args-8f2af15363304c6682112b8a6a3fc974/" style="
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    " frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-downloads allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>
</div>

                       </div>
                </div>
```

there is a div tag with css between the declaration of my django dash app in template and the rendering of the iframe. Does someone knows where it comes from?

I am guessing it may be something buggy from django dash, in that case, how to override that css property?

EDIT: i went to search in the github of django plotly dash and here is the function causing the issue:

```
@register.inclusion_tag("django_plotly_dash/plotly_app.html", takes_context=True)
def plotly_app(context, name=None, slug=None, da=None, ratio=0.1, use_frameborder=False, initial_arguments=None):
    'Insert a dash application using a html iframe'

    fbs = '1' if use_frameborder else '0'

    dstyle = """
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: %s%%;
    height: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    """ % (ratio*100)

    istyle = """
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    """

    cache_id = store_initial_arguments(context['request'], initial_arguments)

    da, app = _locate_daapp(name, slug, da, cache_id=cache_id)

    sandbox_settings = SANDBOX_STRING
    
    return locals()
```

It looks like I need to find a way to use istyle and not dstyle

Comment: Hey @Murcielago , were you able to figure out a way to deal with this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `plotly_app` template tag expands as defined in [`plotly_app.html`](https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash/blob/master/django_plotly_dash/templates/django_plotly_dash/plotly_app.html) :

```html
<div style="{{dstyle}}">
  <iframe src="{{app.base_url}}" style="{{istyle}}" frameborder="{{fbs}}" sandbox="{{sandbox_settings}}"></iframe>
</div>
```

You might want to just comment out the outer div. You could also try to use another template, ie. :

- `plotly_app_bootstrap`, for use with responsive layouts using the Bootstrap library
- `plotly_direct`, allows the direct insertion of html into a template, instead of embedding it in an iframe.

I would suggest playing a bit with the different templates without any extra styles, before eventually adding them (specifically those you add in the outer divs) if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I fought with this for a *very* long time. Here's what worked for me:

- Use `{% plotly_app_bootstrap name='DashApp' aspect='16by9' initial_arguments=dash %}`, which gives the internal iframe the bootstrap class `.embed-responsive-item`
- Nest it in a `<body>` and `<div>` with these settings (I haven't bothered to test which ones are important, I'm just happy it works)
- Override the CSS styling of the `.embed-responsive-item` class

Code:

```html
{%load plotly_dash%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background-color: green; box-sizing: border-box; height: 100%; padding: 0px;">
<head>
    <title>Plotly in Django</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">
</head>
  

<body style="
    margin: 0px; 
    /* padding: 10px;  */
    background-color: blue; 
    height: 100vh; 
    overflow-y: hidden !important; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
">
                
  <div style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    {% plotly_app_bootstrap name='DashApp' aspect='16by9' initial_arguments=dash %}
  </div>


  <style>
    .embed-responsive-item {
      /* Your styles here */
      /* padding: 20px; */
      background-color: red;
      height: 100vh !important;
      width: 100vw !important;
      overflow-y: scroll !important;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style>

</body>
</html>
```